# Dependency for org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to integrate spark streaming with kafka. I am unable to resolve dependency for `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils`. Below is my build.sbt:

```
name := "StreamingTest"

version := "1.0"

organization := "com.sundogsoftware"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.0-preview2" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "3.0.0-preview2",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.0-preview2",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.0.0-preview2" % "provided",
"org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "2.0.0"

)
```

I am using following imports in my project:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext, sql}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.{DStream, InputDStream}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
```

All the dependecies are resolved except `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils`. I am using spark version 3.0.0-preview2 and scala version 2.12.10.

Comment: You shouldn't import `org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka`, by the way

Comment: I have removed. but I ma still getting the error(object kafka is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming) on import statement.

Comment: Because it isn't. See answer below